# npm run crashes when using Spacemacs

Tags: reactjs, npm, vim, emacs, spacemacs

For some reason after I have run my react server and I use spacemacs in to edit any file it gives me the following error.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/bitvivaz/Documents/tutorials/Website Development/reactJS/react-props-pokedex/src/components/.#Pokegame.js'
```

Note this is time I was trying to edit Pokegame.js. I however am capable to use vs code without any problems and can edit anything. I assume its the way spacemacs edit's a buffer or creates a temporarily file and the overwrites the old one?

Is there a way to fix this perhaps cause I've got quite costumed to spacemacs short cuts and keep pressing them in vs code. I use rjsx mode btw.

Thanks and sorry for any conveniences.

Comment: This just started today for me too. I can't see what's changed in my environment.
I'm running vanilla emacs 26.3, not spacemacs, on a Mac, with yarn and react 16.13.1. I'm also running rjsx, but I'd be really surprised if that's significant.

As a workaround, I've done
M-X Eval Expression
(setq create-lockfiles nil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary solution:

Try:

```
M-X Eval Expression
(setq create-lockfiles nil)
```

This has consequences, but will at least let us work for now with Emacs and React until someone figures out what's really going on.